# magento 2 adding product to catagory using rest

Tags: magento2, php, rest-api

i am trying to add products to a specific category but i have two issues.

1. when adding it to category it overrides the previous category but i would like to keep it in both categories and not removing it from the previous category.
2. how can i remove the category that was assigned if condition was not met.

   ```
       if (($product['price'] * 1.20) < $old_price_check) {
       $customData[] = array('attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["86"]);
   } else {
       $customData[] = array('attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["86"]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to fetch Products Current assigned category, then you can perform the below task:

- If condition match merge New Category Id array with assigned Category Ids array.
- If condition not match pass New Category Id array.

**Updated**

```
$oldCat = [10, 11];
$newCat = [21, 22, 23];
$catIds = array_unique(array_merge($oldCat,$newCat));
$customData[] = array('attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => $catIds);
```

Comment: How do I fetch products current assigned catagory? How can I merge the new catagory?

Comment: As you are updating product using Rest before doing that you can fetch product information

Comment: how can i push the new value to the array?

Comment: $customData[] = array('attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["86"]);

Comment: I have updated the answer. hope this help